# Upload image codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, upload

I try to upload an image with CodeIgniter. The image has to be send to a folder and the path send to the database. When I do submit, it doesn't do anything. The var_dump of ($story_img) shows:

```
string(8) "/images/"
```

This is my code:

```
if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'POST') {
        $config['upload_path'] = '/images/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size']    = '1000000';
        $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
        $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
        $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('story_img');
        $image_path = $this->upload->data();
        $story_img = $image_path['full_path'];

        echo var_dump($story_img);

        $story_text = $this->input->post("story_text");
        $users_id = $this->input->post('users_id');


        $this->form_validation->set_rules('story_text', 'Story text', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('story_img', 'Story image ', 'callback__image_upload');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() != FALSE) {

            $new_story = new Story_model();
            $new_story->Story_text = $story_text;
            $new_story->Users_id = $users_id;
            $new_story->Story_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
            $new_story->Story_img = $story_img;


            $this->Story_model->addStory($new_story);
        }
    }
```

`var_dump of $image_path`

```
array(14) { ["file_name"]=> string(0) "" ["file_type"]=> string(0) "" ["file_path"]=> string(8) "/images/" ["full_path"]=> string(8) "/images/" ["raw_name"]=> string(0) "" ["orig_name"]=> string(0) "" ["client_name"]=> string(0) "" ["file_ext"]=> string(0) "" ["file_size"]=> NULL ["is_image"]=> bool(false) ["image_width"]=> NULL ["image_height"]=> NULL ["image_type"]=> string(0) "" ["image_size_str"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Comment: Could you make `var_dump( $image_path )`

Comment: @mcklayin this my var_dump of $image_path -> array(14) { ["file_name"]=> string(0) "" ["file_type"]=> string(0) "" ["file_path"]=> string(8) "/images/" ["full_path"]=> string(8) "/images/" ["raw_name"]=> string(0) "" ["orig_name"]=> string(0) "" ["client_name"]=> string(0) "" ["file_ext"]=> string(0) "" ["file_size"]=> NULL ["is_image"]=> bool(false) ["image_width"]=> NULL ["image_height"]=> NULL ["image_type"]=> string(0) "" ["image_size_str"]=> string(0) "" }

Comment: It seems you haven't upload image. 
`["is_image"]=> bool(false)`

Comment: @mcklayin so where is the mistake then?

Comment: please add a `var_dump($_FILES)`

Comment: @mcklayin this result -> array(1) { ["story_img"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(38) "Screen Shot 2015-04-25 at 11.50.37.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(36) "/Applications/MAMP/tmp/php/phpyTeFnV" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(104250) } }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that our form field name is story_img?
Try to add conditionals:

```
if($this->upload->do_upload('story_img'))
{ 
   //your code...
}
```

And try to display smth in conditional,to see if you pass it.

Comment: <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

            <label for="story_img">Image</label>
            <input type="file"  name="story_img" id="story_img">

            <br>

            <button type="submit" name="location" id="location">Add</button>

        </form>

Comment: @user3071261 Did you try any other images with different extensions(.jpg, .gif) ?

Comment: @user3071261 Try `var_dump($this->upload->display_errors())` after `$this->upload->do_upload('story_img');` And check a permissions on ypur upload_path

Comment: something was wrong with my bad apparantly, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
$image_path = $this->upload->data();

foreach ($image_path as $info) {
   $path=$info['full_path'];
}

echo $path;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you mentioned `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag

Comment: If you think this is actually the problem, you could make this into an answer: phrase it more like a statement and explain how not specifying this would match the symptoms the poster is seeing.